# Why does value change in string literal

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior, string-literals

```
main()
{
  char *c="abhishek";
  int i;
  c[2]=90;
  for(i=0;i<12;i++)
  {
    printf("%c",c[0])
  }
}
```

Here the output is `abZishek`. But this should result in a bus error because this is a string literal and we can not change its value. Why does the value of `c` change?

Comment: Modifying a string literal gives undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: It is just a chunk of bytes in memory.

Comment: This shouldnt even compile, a string literal is of type `const char[]`

Comment: This is precisely why you shouldn't use a non-const `char *` to point to a string literal.

Comment: Because it's not a __constant__ literal. Use `const char *c`.

Comment: @Paranaix, It shouldn't as of C++11. Before that, it was an exception and AFAIK, all versions of C allow it.

Comment: @Paranaix Although deprecated, a conversion from character literal to `char*` existed in C++03.

Comment: I doubt the output will be abZishek if you don't use the loop index. And backup your datas before using it, because accessing with index 9 is UB.

Answer (score 7):

According to section 2.14.5 paragraph **§** 11 of the C++ standard, it invokes undefined behavior:

> The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.

This means anything can happen and indeed something has happened. You must not make any assumptions about what may happen when you invoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: Is this rule  also true for c or it is applicable only in c++

Comment: yes, in C also the behavior is undefined if a program attempts to modify any string literals.

Answer (score 3):

"Undefined behaviour" does not guarantee a "bus error" or any other sort of error. In general it cannot be easily detected so your compiler is not required to bother. Here, it does not bother. However, in doing this you may cause unpredictable or strange things to happen.

You're also missing library includes and a return type for `main`; which C++ book are you using?

Comment: i did not not include libraries because it is obvious.what is the need to include.I am a final year student in Btech and a want to be a java programmer>and i am certified in java .i want to read c and c++ only up to level that i can pass the written test of compnies.i am using test your c skills in c  for practice and head first  c for theory.What else i should use??

Comment: @user3335653: It's not "obvious" to use at all that you've been including the correct ones if you don't show them to us. Here is your book recommendation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list